# my internet is not working on ubuntu?

Tags: internet, connection, ubuntu-12.10

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and I found that Twitter.com is not work for me. I have tried to install plugin but it's not worked for me on Firefox.

In chrome net is running slow as Firefox. When I have used Win7 on same hardware I feel it's fast. Someone can help me to troubleshoot this problem.

For me I have installed 12.04 then upgrade my system. I thing problem will solve after upgrade but it's not worked.

Someone help me on it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways which could lead to symptoms you describe. Things to think about are:

- can you see *any* webpages?
- what is your connection? (e.g. cable→router→wifi→laptop, DSL→router→wifi→laptop, DSL→router→ethernet→laptop?)
- can you access Internet from:

  - your computer, but a different place, e.g. at friend's?
  - a friend's computer at your place?
  - your computer, from a different operating system (e.g. a LiveCD, or installed Windows)

If you try these things out, it might give you a rough idea where the problem is.

Also, consider asking your question on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: what I found is win7 run internet faster. Setting IP solve twitter.com but I still not got some site working when I set Google DNS.